# ibpy interactive broker's python api not working for placing order

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers

I have following sample code, when I try to run it for the first time, it worked:

```
from ib.opt import Connection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order

def make_contract(symbol, sec_type, exch, prim_exch, curr):

    Contract.m_symbol = symbol
    Contract.m_secType = sec_type
    Contract.m_exchange = exch
    Contract.m_primaryExch = prim_exch
    Contract.m_currency = curr
    return Contract



def make_order(action,quantity, price = None):

    if price is not None:
        order = Order()
        order.m_orderType = 'LMT'
        order.m_totalQuantity = quantity
        order.m_action = action
        order.m_lmtPrice = price

    else:
        order = Order()
        order.m_orderType = 'MKT'
        order.m_totalQuantity = quantity
        order.m_action = action


    return order


cid = 100

while __name__ == "__main__":

    conn = Connection.create(port=7496, clientId=999)
    conn.connect()
    oid = cid
    cont = make_contract('AAPL', 'STK', 'SMART', 'SMART', 'USD')
    offer = make_order('BUY', 1, 200)
    conn.placeOrder(oid, cont, offer)
    conn.disconnect()
    x = raw_input('enter to resend')
    cid += 1
```

as i run the script for the first time, the interface of IB pops up a window and says configuration information for paper trading from API. However the second, third time I run it, the pop up information never shows up again which confuse me. Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if __name__ == "__main__":`. I wonder what will happen if one uses while loop?

Comment: I don't know enough python to answer but you should always register a handler for errors.  I would do a registerAll with a handler that just prints the msg.  Then you can see the problem.  Look at other ibpy questions for an example. If I had to guess you might need a `global cid` declaration in the loop.  You will have to keep track of the last cid used for your whole life and always increment by 1, so the 100 will need to change as well.

Comment: I am using iPython which means I can run each line of code one at a time, actually I am not compiling it in terminal but using iPython and run one at a time, so the problem is not in if __name__ == "__main__" and I am sure about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned it should be if **name** == "**main**":

What you are doing there is running an infinite loop that connects to the IB API, places an order, disconnects and repeats the same process.

The popup is probably one of the API warnings that once accepted doesn't show up again so that explains why you don't see it again.

Your order is quite likely placed and should show up in TWS unless it's resulting in an error which you won't see in TWS.

As others have alluded to what you need to do is firstly not use iPython notebook as it's not going to give you a good view of what's going on. Change your code to look like this and you'll be able to see what's going on:

```
from ib.opt import Connection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order
import time

def make_contract(symbol, sec_type, exch, prim_exch, curr):

    Contract.m_symbol = symbol
    Contract.m_secType = sec_type
    Contract.m_exchange = exch
    Contract.m_primaryExch = prim_exch
    Contract.m_currency = curr
    return Contract


def make_order(action,quantity, price = None):

    if price is not None:
        order = Order()
        order.m_orderType = 'LMT'
        order.m_totalQuantity = quantity
        order.m_action = action
        order.m_lmtPrice = price

    else:
        order = Order()
        order.m_orderType = 'MKT'
        order.m_totalQuantity = quantity
        order.m_action = action


    return order


cid = 100

def handleAll(msg):
    print msg

if __name__ == "__main__":

    conn = Connection.create(port=7496, clientId=999)
    conn.connect()
    conn.registerAll(handleAll)
    oid = cid
    cont = make_contract('AAPL', 'STK', 'SMART', 'SMART', 'USD')
    offer = make_order('BUY', 1, 200)
    conn.placeOrder(oid, cont, offer)
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: hi kbcool I am trying your code it works, but only for the first placed order. On TWS it shows the buying record for AAPL for 200 shares, but when I change AAPL to MSFT and execute it once again, it does not show the second record.

Comment: and I do have changed cid from 100 to 500, it says Server Version: 76
TWS Time at connection:20170117 08:55:14 EST
<openOrder orderId=500, contract=<ib.ext.Contract.Contract object at 0x0000000002E23C88>, order=<ib.ext.Order.Order object at 0x0000000002E23C50>, orderState=<ib.ext.OrderState.OrderState object at 0x0000000002E23CF8>>
<orderStatus orderId=500, status=PreSubmitted, filled=0, remaining=1, avgFillPrice=0.0, permId=170794483, parentId=0, lastFillPrice=0.0, clientId=999, whyHeld=locate>
<openOrderEnd>
<managedAccounts accountsList=DU431755>

Comment: Ok, I think i figured out the problem, its because I didnt give time.sleep() in between these lines of code. Remember its request/response between local/TWS server, always kindly give some relief time before anything connects.

Comment: You can just get the nextValidId message and use that instead of changing cid all the time.  Also, once you get that message you know you're connected and don't need any sleeps.